# R map mit ggplot2 - Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data

Tags: r

I want to create a map and colour the zip-code regions with a ratio per zip-code.

Maybe you don't need the data but the shapesfiles can be found here (16 MB) https://www.suche-postleitzahl.org/download_v1/wgs84/mittel/plz-5stellig/shapefile/plz-5stellig.shp.zip

And if there's an issue with non-matching zip-codes from the randomly generated, here are the real ones (1 MB) https://www.suche-postleitzahl.org/download_files/public/zuordnung_plz_ort.csv

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1) ##I set a seed, just to ensure reproducibility
zip <- sample(100:201, 5000, replace = TRUE)
outcome <- rbinom(5000, 1, 0.23)
df <- data.frame(id, outcome, zip) %>% as_tibble()
new_df <- df %>% group_by(zip) %>% summarise(ratio = mean(outcome))

library(ggplot2)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(ggthemes)

setwd("path")

shape <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "plz-5stellig")
shape_df <- fortify(shape, note="Berlin")

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=new_df, map=shape_df,
                    aes(fill=outcome, map_id=zip),
                    color="#7f7f7f", size=0.25)
gg
```

Which unfortunately gives me:

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data
>   (102): fill, map_id

Whats the issue here? How can I match the Aesthetics to the zip-code?

My aim is to produce a map like https://blog.eoda.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Kartenvisualisierung-mit-R-Haushaltsverteilung-in-Kassel.png

Answer (score 0):

By grouping and summarising the dataframe you end up with less than 5000 rows, because your call of `sample` allows for ZIP codes to get drawn more than once. Duplicated ZIP codes then get condensed into one value by `group_by` + `summarise`. Your dataframe `new_df` now has 102 rows and if you want to plot it every defined aesthetics has to be of length 1 or 102 (number of rows in your dataframe). Instead you try to enter vectors of the length 5000 (the ones you initialized at the beginning).

What you have to do is update the variables `zip` and `outcome` after you condensed your dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1) ##I set a seed, just to ensure reproducibility
zip <- sample(100:201, 5000, replace = TRUE)
outcome <- rbinom(5000, 1, 0.23)
df <- data.frame(id, outcome, zip) %>% as_tibble()
new_df <- df %>% group_by(zip) %>% summarise(ratio = mean(outcome))
zip <- new_df %>% pull(zip) # only get the zips in your sample
outcome <- new_df %>% pull(outcome) # only get the outcomes in your sample

library(ggplot2)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(ggthemes)

setwd("path")

shape <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "plz-5stellig")
shape_df <- fortify(zips, note="Berlin")

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=new_df, map=shape_df,
                    aes(fill=outcome, map_id=zip),
                    color="#7f7f7f", size=0.25)
gg
```